# calling a second method from within a xmlrpc request

Tags: php, arrays, xml-rpc

I have this method `Answers`, that uses this struct:

```
struct PCLAnswersReq
Members
string                             | UserName
integer                            | SessionID
array of struct PCLAnswerUnit      | Answers
```

the struct `PCLAnswerUnit` looks like:

```
Members
integer | QuestionID
string  | Answer
```

So the `PCLAnswersReq` has the username, sessionID, and an array of the structure `PCLAnswerUnit`,which is fine, but I can't seem to work out how to get that second struct in.

My request (using php xml-rpc) looks like this:

```
xmlrpc_encode_request('PCLAnswers',  array("UserName"=>$uname,"SessionID"=>$sesid,"Answers"=>xmlrpc_encode_request('PCLAnswerUnit',array("QuestionID"=>'',"Answer"=>$questions))));
```

This of course is causing a fault:

```
"request contains string value where array expected [request : parameter 1 : struct mapped to type PCLAnswersReq : member Answers mapped to type PCLAnswerUnit[]]"
```

I tried removing the second xmlrpc request, and just pointing `Answers` to an array of QuestionID and Answer, but that did not work either.

Any guidance is helpful.

Thanks!

'UPDATE'

When the xml-rpc request is modified to this:

```
xmlrpc_encode_request('PCLAnswers',  array("UserName"=>$uname,"SessionID"=>$sesid,"Answers"=>array()));
```

it works fine. However, when I pass it the array of '$questions' it fails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the input method on the server should be in this order:
return_type,xmlrpcString,xmlrpcString,xmlrpcArray

You probably have it mixed up somewhere. The return type is first followed by your three parameters.